Write parquet files with more than the default partition size
If the default partition bytes size is 128MB, in my understanding it is impossible to write parquets with for instance 600MB. How can I ensure that I don´t have small files in DataLake using coalesce if I don´t change the partition bytes size.

spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes is "the maximum number of bytes to pack into a single partition when reading files.", i.e. it doesn't affect how files are written.

You can determine the effective number of partition for coalesce like below.You can use df.count()* df.columns to find approx size of data.
# Step 1: Calculate the number of partitions you want
num_partitions = (df.count() * df.columns) // (600 * 1024 * 1024)  # Assuming 600MB files

# Step 2: Coalesce to reduce the number of partitions 
df_coalesced = df.coalesce(num_partitions)

To improve accuracy , you can also use below approach to calculate byte size of your data
sample_row_size = len(str(df.head(1)))  # Estimate the size of the first row (in bytes)

# Total size of the DataFrame in bytes
df_size_in_bytes = df.count() * sample_row_size

# Calculate the number of partitions based on actual byte size
num_partitions = df_size_in_bytes // (600 * 1024 * 1024)

